# Is there a way to set an application appearance different with the windows appearence?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-vista

e.g. set the application appearance to classic, but set the window appearance to Aero style.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WPF or Silverlight you can use Themes. [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx) on the MSDN goes into some detail.

[WPF Themes](http://wpfthemes.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex has examples.

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfskins.aspx) on Code Project has some more information.

You'd actually want just one unchangeable theme and that would be the Windows Classic one.